# Azure DevOps REST API returns a 403 when using the system OAuth token during a build

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm running a script:

```
# Variables
$organization = "****"
$project = "****"
$repositoryId = "****"
$pullRequestId = $env:BUILD_PULLREQUEST_ID

$pat = "Bearer $env:System_AccessToken"
$featureReleaseUrl = "http://" + $env:prSourceBranchName + ".azurewebsites.net"

$body = @"
    {
        "comments": [
            {
                "content": "Link naar feature release $featureReleaseUrl"
            }
        ]
    }
"@ 

$createThreadInPRUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/pullRequests/$pullRequestId/threads?api-version=5.0"
if ($pullRequestId) {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $createThreadInPRUrl -Headers @{Authorization = $pat} -Body $body -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json'
}
```

When it runs it returns a:

> ```
> ##[error]The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
> ```

I've created a `Personal Access Tokens` in my personal settings.

I've also created this script:

```
# Variables
$organization = "****"
$project = "****"
$buildId = $****

$pat = "Bearer $env:System_AccessToken"

if (!$env:Build_PullRequest_SourceBranchName) {
    $retrieveSourceBranchFromBuildURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/$buildId" + "?api-version=5.0"
    $buildInformation = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $retrieveSourceBranchFromBuildURL -Headers @{Authorization = $pat } -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json'
    $SourceBranchFromBuild = $buildInformation.sourceBranch.split('/')[-1]

    Write-Host "### no Build PullRequest SourceBranchName available ###"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=prSourceBranchName;]"$SourceBranchFromBuild


}
```

And this runs fine. The difference between the first and second script is that the first is a POST and the second a GET. But they both use the $pat token.

Comment: No, the difference between the first and second is that they are **completely different APIs**. Does your build account have permissions to your Git repo(s)/PRs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the token you used is `System.AccessToken`, if you don't have access permission of Pull Request, you will also could not operate it.

Go Project Setting--> Repositories--> Repository you want to access, locate your account or the group you are in. Check the permission state of **`Contribute to pull requests`**.

You must have this `Contribute to pull requests` permission allowed, so that you can add the comment to PR.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would have been helpful if Azure would return an error about not having permissions.

Comment: Aha, got this feeling. I would help you report this inconvenience message issue to relevant product team.